# AWS AMPLIFY: How to specify auth for custom lambda resolvers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

How to specify all Cognito users can access custom lambda resolver

```
type Query {
   tasks: [Task] @function(name: "lambda1-${env}")  
   getTask(id:ID!): Task @function(name: "lambda1-${env}")  
}

type Task {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

I am getting unauthorized when doing

```
    const taskList = await API.graphql({
      query: tasks,
      authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working.

```
type Query {
   tasks: [Task] @function(name: "lambda1-${env}") @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: userPools }])
   getTask(id:ID!): Task @function(name: "lambda1-${env}")
}

type Task {
  id: ID! @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: userPools }])
  name: String! @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: userPools }])
}

const taskList = await API.graphql({
  query: tasks,
  authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
});
```